# Avoiding circular dependency in implementationFactory

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I am using Azure Functions in-proc.

One of my functions is an endpoint that can do many things depending on the request data, based on said request data a command class' execute method will be called. I would like to register those command classes as they can use services themselves.

The `CommandService` itself also functions as a gateway, currently, allowing calls to be made from the command classes to the API that originally called the function that is not a direct response to it. Basically sometimes I can reply directly and just give the answer in an httpresponse back from the function.

However sometimes processing needs to be done and the answer will be delayed, so I send back a httpresponse saying that I got the request but a processed answer to the request will come later. Once processing is done sending the answer is then a request initiated on my end to the API that originally send the request to me.

Here lies the problem, in that trying to inject the `CommandService` into the command class causes the circular dependency, however I want to use reflection to automatically populate the CommandService with all the commands that exist so I can just add new commands without having to worry about manually creating and maintaining a massive list of registrations.

```
// This is a method called in Startup.Configure()
public void ConfigureCommands(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    var commandClasses = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Command)).GetTypes().Where(x => typeof(Command).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsAbstract).ToArray();

    foreach (var command in commandClasses)
        builder.Services.AddTransient(command);

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICommandService>(x =>
    {
        var service = x.GetRequiredService<CommandService>();
        foreach (var command in commandClasses)
            service.RegisterCommand((Command)x.GetRequiredService(command)); // This causes the circular dependency, because a command tries to inject ICommandService

        return service;
    });
}
```

Then later in my function I parse the request data, check validity etc and eventually pass the result to my `CommandService` which will then find the command to be executed.

```
// This is a method in CommandService
public async Task<CommandResponse> ExecuteCommand(CommandRequestData requestData)
{
    _logger.LogDebug($"Command received:\n{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData)}");

    return await _commands.First(x => x.CommandName == request.name).Execute(requestData);
}
```

Since I don't have an opening, as far as I can tell, between the `Startup.Configure()` call and the function call, how would I go about calling my registrations/initialization?

I've tried calling `builder.Service.BuildServiceProvider()` but it seems at this point not everything is registered yet, so that is a dead-end.

I would like to keep things concise by keeping things related to this API in the same service class, so is there a clean way to do this or am I better off putting talking back to the API in a different service from handeling the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Dirty and quick answer

Replace:

```cs
var service = x.GetRequiredService<CommandService>();
```

with:

```cs
var logger = x.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CommandService>>();
var service = new CommandService(logger);
```

Resolve and add other dependencies of `CommandService` if needed.

#### Full answer

With the following solution, I'm assuming that *"an endpoint that can do many things depending on the request data"* is untouchable and cannot be changed, so we have to roll with command type discovery based on string name included in command request data.

First, instead of scanning command names every time a command is needed, we can do it only once. We can use the fact that built-in DI supports resolving sequences of the same dependency, so we can just ask DI to provide all implementations of `Command` and create a nice dictionary from it, taking command name as key.

```cs
public class CommandLookup : ICommandLookup
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Type> _commandTypes;

    public CommandLookup(IEnumerable<Command> commands)
    {
        _commandTypes = commands.ToDictionary(x => x.CommandName, x => x.GetType());
    }

    public Type GetCommandType(string name)
    {
        return _commandTypes[name];
    }
}

public interface ICommandLookup
{
    Type GetCommandType(string name);
}
```

But that will only give us command type, we still have to initialize it. And best would be to not do it manually. We can achieve this with factory pattern using `IServiceProvider`. It is worth noticing, that such implementation of factory is based on service locator pattern, which [for some is viewed as anti-pattern](https://www.jimmybogard.com/service-locator-is-not-an-anti-pattern/). But, given the statement at the beginning of this answer, we'll just roll with it.

```cs
public class CommandFactory : ICommandFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public CommandFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public Command CreateCommand(Type commandType)
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(commandType) as Command;
    }
}

public interface ICommandFactory
{
    Command CreateCommand(Type commandType);
}
```

The command itself will have to contain these minimal information, name and abstract method for execution:

```cs
public abstract class Command
{
    public abstract string CommandName { get; }

    public abstract Task<CommandResponse> Execute(CommandRequestData requestData);
}
```

Command service will no longer need registration part, just the execution logic. Command type is resolved using lookup, command itself is initialized using command factory while passing obtained type.

```cs
public class CommandService : ICommandService
{
    private readonly ICommandLookup _commandLookup;
    private readonly ICommandFactory _commandFactory;
    private readonly ILogger<CommandService> _logger;

    public CommandService(
        ICommandLookup commandLookup,
        ICommandFactory commandFactory,
        ILogger<CommandService> logger)
    {
        _commandLookup = commandLookup;
        _commandFactory = commandFactory;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<CommandResponse> ExecuteCommand(CommandRequestData requestData)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Command received:\n{commandData}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData));

        var commandType = _commandLookup.GetCommandType(requestData.Name);
        var command = _commandFactory.CreateCommand(commandType);

        return await command.Execute(requestData);
    }
}
```

And finally, registration part within `IServiceCollection`:

```cs
public void ConfigureCommands(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    var commandClasses = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Command))
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(x => typeof(Command).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsAbstract)
        .ToArray();

    foreach (var commandType in commandClasses)
    {
        builder.Services.AddTransient(commandType);
        builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(Command), commandType);
    }

    builder.Services.AddScoped<ICommandService, CommandService>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICommandLookup, CommandLookup>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<ICommandFactory, CommandFactory>();
}
```

Some explanation to this section:

- each command it registered twice, first for lookup purposes, so we can resolve all commands by `Command` type, second time for factory so with concrete type we can resolve only the command we actually want
- lookup is registered as singleton because we want to scan the commands only once - when the lookup is initially created

##### Worth reading

- [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)

##### Libraries worth getting known

- [Scrutor - assembly scanning-based service registration](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor)
- [MediatR - dispatching of request, commands, events & more](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR)

Comment: I absolutely love the explanation you gave. I've since moved to splitting the commandservice class in two, one handling requests and one handling communication back, because I just wanted to get it working. But I am really liking this! I'll try and implement this before I move on to another part of the project, thank you for the amazing answer.